# Expanded widget takes full height of the screen irrespective of its children

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I am using a dynamic bottom sheet with a column as its child. The last child of this column is a grid view. For some small screen devices, the content of this bottom sheet my get overflow so I wrapped the grid view inside an expanded widget. Now its content are scrollable if they are overflowing.

But the problem here is, even if the contents of the grid view are not overflowing (screen size is big enough) it still expands to full screen leaving empty space at the bottom. I am trying to solve this issue for past 3 days but no result. I tried various combinations of parent and child widget but nothing gives the satisfying result.

The result I am expecting is that the grid view should scroll when contents are overflowing and if not then it should take only the required space and not the entire screen.

Here is my entire code, the grid view with the problem is at the end :

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 225, 225)),
                        ),
                        //color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 15),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.save,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                              size: 28.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: (){},
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 13.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*(2/3)),
                                            child: Text(
                                              'PDF Name',
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              maxLines: 2,
                                              softWrap: true,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.edit,
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                                              size: 16.0,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "PDF Size",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                                child: Divider(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                  thickness: 1.1,
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 4),
                            child: Text(
                              "Share/Save File to",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                                child: Divider(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                  thickness: 1.1,
                                ),
                              )
                          ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GridView.count(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.25,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.phone_android, color: Colors.pink, title: 'Internal Storage', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.folder, color: Colors.blueAccent, title: 'My Documents', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.add_to_drive_rounded, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 150, 0), title: 'Google Drive', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.mail, color: Colors.lightBlue, title: 'Send to Email', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      },
    );
```

Here is the output image:

[image]

It even slides under that phone's status bar at the top. How can I avoid that as well.

This is the result I am expecting:

**Case 1: When it is overflowing, this works fine as I have wrapped grid view in an expanded widget, it becomes scrollable -**

[image]

**Case 2: When screen size is sufficient for the children, below image should be the output, but I get empty space at bottom instead-**

[image]

Okay, I figured it out finally. For the Status Bar overlapping part giving safe area and all was not working and as suggested by Sagar Acharya using FractionallySizedBox did prevented it but it forced the bottom sheet to take up full screen irrespective of its content height leaving empty space after its last item. Instead I used constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)*0.95) which did not force sheet to take full height and also prevented it from overlapping status bar.

For the other problem I first removed expanded from top of my grid view and wrapped my whole column (containing all items of the bottom sheet) with SingleChildScrollView. Now it keeps the content wrapped until sheet reaches full screen height and when it does it becomes scrollable.

But still there is one thing I want to change, in my output my whole content of the bottom sheet is scrollable but I just want the grid view children to be scrollable, the top most 'PDF Name' and 'Share/Save File to' should not scroll along with it. Any ideas how I can do that. I tried using SingleChildScrollView on grid view instead of Column but it did not work (the element overflowed when the sheet reached full height)

Here is my code:

```
showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return Container(
                //height: 900,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)*0.95),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 225, 225)),
                          ),
                          //color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 15),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.save,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                                size: 28.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Material(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: (){},
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 13.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*(2/3)),
                                              child: Text(
                                                'PDF Name',
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                maxLines: 2,
                                                softWrap: true,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                              child: Icon(
                                                Icons.edit,
                                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                                                size: 16.0,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "PDF Size",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 12.0,
                                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                                  child: Divider(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                    thickness: 1.1,
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 4),
                              child: Text(
                                "Share/Save File to",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                                  child: Divider(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                    thickness: 1.1,
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                          ]
                      ),
                      GridView.count(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        //physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                        childAspectRatio: 1.25,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.phone_android, color: Colors.pink, title: 'Internal Storage', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.folder, color: Colors.blueAccent, title: 'My Documents', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.add_to_drive_rounded, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 150, 0), title: 'Google Drive', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.mail, color: Colors.lightBlue, title: 'Send to Email', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),

                          /*FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                          FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),*/
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      },
    );
```

Any help would me much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: can you add the screen shot of  required output

Comment: i will update the answer if you show me the exactly what output you want

Comment: I have updated my question, I added 2 new images, the last image CASE 2 is what i expect when children are not overflowing instead I get output as shown in first image (the empty space one)

Comment: to make your widget take only minimum space available set shrinkWrap property to true inside your Column/Row

Comment: Is there a shrinkWrap for column as well? How do i set it, it says property shrinkWrap is not defined. And if you are suggesting it for grid view then I already tried that. With that the grid view keeps its children wrapped until the bottom sheet reaches full screen height and then instead of becoming scrollable, its children overflows. For that I used expanded on grid view but that leaves empty space at the bottom.

Comment: i have edited the answer .. you can check

Comment: I will check it

Comment: I had to make 2 edits in your updated answer, first bottom sheet is to be dynamic with isScrollControlled: true and instead of giving fixed size to top most container I did constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)*0.95), because I want it to keep expanding to full screen while keeping its content wrapped (this is important) so that no empty space is left at the bottom and once it reaches full height and still more children of grid view are to displayed then only grid view should become scrollable.

Comment: In your updated answer only grid view is scrollable that's perfect but if its children are less then empty space is left at the bottom.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check the code that I added at the end, that's how it should work and in that too, I would prefer if only grid view is scrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I think this is the answer you wanted

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test11111/test1.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';



class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: Get.height* 0.4,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                bottom: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 225, 225)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 15),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.save,
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                                    size: 28.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Material(
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: (){},
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 13.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*(2/3)),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'PDF Name',
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    maxLines: 2,
                                                    softWrap: true,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.edit,
                                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                                                    size: 16.0,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "PDF Size",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                                      child: Divider(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                        thickness: 1.1,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 4),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Share/Save File to",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                                      child: Divider(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                        thickness: 1.1,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: GridView.count(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                              crossAxisCount: 3,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              childAspectRatio: 1.25,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.phone_android, color: Colors.pink, title: 'Internal Storage', press: (){}),
                                FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.folder, color: Colors.blueAccent, title: 'My Documents', press: (){}),
                                FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.add_to_drive_rounded, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 150, 0), title: 'Google Drive', press: (){}),
                                FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.mail, color: Colors.lightBlue, title: 'Send to Email', press: (){}),
                                FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class FileSaveCard extends StatelessWidget {
  FileSaveCard(
      {Key? key,
      required this.icon,
      required this.color,
      required this.title,
      required this.press})
      : super(key: key);
  IconData icon;
  Color color;
  String title;
  VoidCallback press;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(icon), color: color, onPressed: press),
          Text(title)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it does not work

Comment: The problem still remains the same. If the number of children of the grid view are less. The bottom sheet still leaves empty space = half screen height - height of its contents. I wrapped your updated code in dynamic bottom sheet.

Comment: can u  update the full code with my updated code

Comment: The code in my question?

Comment: I have added full code according to your updated code in my question at the end.

Comment: But it did not solve my problem, its practically the same thing I asked question in the first place. Even Sagar helped me somewhat like you did but in the end yours and Sagar's answer did not gave the desired results.

Comment: Check my last updated code in that I want only grid view to scrollable, if you can help me with that I will mark it accepted. Because then your help would become greater than Sagar's.

Comment: in the above example only gird view is scrolling...check the example first

Comment: Only grid view is scrolling I know and that's because you wrapped it inside Expanded and the problem with Expanded is that it forces the bottom sheet to take full screen and leaving empty space at the bottom which is the problem I want to resolve in the first place. So Expanded cannot be used on the grid view like this. The code I shared at the begining had the same result your code is producing now. You just used fixed height in your top container that is the reason the empty space is not visible at the bottom. I want the height of container to be flexible and should wrap its content at the

Comment: same time until its height reaches screen height (excluding status bar) and then it should be scrollable (only grid view).

Comment: Please check the code I added at the end in my question. That's the result I wanted and in that too only grid view should be scrollable (only when bottom sheet reaches full screen height before that it should not be scrollable and its content should be wrapped without any empty space at the bottom). That's why I am asking you to help me with this and then I can mark your answer accepted.

Comment: I hope you understood what my actual question was.

Answer (score 1):

Ok So from the code i see you are using things in wrong manner.

1. If you are using the isScrollControlled =true it will use the complete height of the device as you have used the expanded and the Column widget as a parent for the children inside it.
2. Next if you do not want the complete height so instead of column you have to use the Wrap widget and remove the expanded from the gridview it will take the height as per the children.
3. If you want the fill modelsheet and the space from top as it overlaps the statusbar you can use the FractionallySizedBox widget

```
FractionallySizedBox(
   heightFactor: 0.95,// This will take 0.05 percent height from the top and show the status bar 
)
```

Note: It can only be used when the isScrolled is true.

so I have created the example from the code that you have provided, Also i have added my icon set so change it as per your needs.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final items = <Widget>[
    //1
    const Icon(
      Icons.phone_android,
      color: Colors.pink,
      semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    ),
    //2
    const Icon(
      Icons.phone_android,
      color: Colors.pink,
      semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    ),
    //3
    const Icon(
      Icons.phone_android,
      color: Colors.pink,
      semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    ),
    //4
    const Icon(
      Icons.phone_android,
      color: Colors.pink,
      semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    ),
    //5
    const Icon(
      Icons.phone_android,
      color: Colors.pink,
      semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    ),
    //6
    const Icon(
      Icons.phone_android,
      color: Colors.pink,
      semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    ),
    
    //Add the same item below this to make it full screen and items below 7 will have the minimum model sheet height.
    //7
    // const Icon(
    //   Icons.phone_android,
    //   color: Colors.pink,
    //   semanticLabel: 'Internal Storage',
    // ),

    //
    // FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.folder, color: Colors.blueAccent, title: 'My Documents', press: (){}),
    // FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.add_to_drive_rounded, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 254, 150, 0), title: 'Google Drive', press: (){}),
    // FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.mail, color: Colors.lightBlue, title: 'Send to Email', press: (){}),
    // FileSaveCard(icon: Icons.share, color: Colors.green, title: 'Share', press: (){}),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: true,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet<dynamic>(
              // use only when you want to use the full height of the screen.
              isScrollControlled: items.length > 6 ? true : false,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
                  return FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: items.length > 6
                        ? 0.95
                        : null, // This widget will add padding from top showing the status bar
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border(
                                bottom: BorderSide(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 225, 225, 225)),
                              ),
                              //color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 15),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.save,
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 2, 136, 209),
                                    size: 28.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Material(
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {},
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            8.0, 13.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                      minWidth: 0,
                                                      maxWidth:
                                                          MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                                  .size
                                                                  .width *
                                                              (2 / 3)),
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    'PDF Name',
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    maxLines: 2,
                                                    softWrap: true,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                          255, 117, 117, 117),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                      5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.edit,
                                                    color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                        255, 2, 136, 209),
                                                    size: 16.0,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                      0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "PDF Size",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 117, 117, 117),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                              child: Divider(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                thickness: 1.1,
                              ),
                            )),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 4),
                              child: Text(
                                "Share/Save File to",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 117, 117),
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 4),
                              child: Divider(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220),
                                thickness: 1.1,
                              ),
                            )),
                          ]),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: items.length > 6 ? 1 : 0,
                            child: GridView.count(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                crossAxisCount: 3,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                childAspectRatio: 1.25,
                                physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                                children: items),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
              },
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Press"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Run the application and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I will try this rightaway

Comment: It is still leaving space at the bottom. I think (half screen height - height of total content) is left out. And if increase the number of children, they are not scrollable

Comment: are you using the FractionallySizedBox, if so remove it. as it will be used when the isScrolled is true.

Comment: Do you mean the children inside  the gridview or the wrap one

Comment: What i want is, max height of the bottom sheet should be (screen height - statusbar height) and it should keep its content wrapped and shouldn't leave any empty space at the bottom. It can expand according to its content height until (screen height - status bar height) and if its content are still not able to fit, the grid view should become scrollable.

Comment: children inside the grid view

Comment: Okay when I removed the FractionallySizedBox as per your suggestion, the empty space at the bottom is gone. But still the grid view children are not scrollable if they are many

Comment: Ok so initially you have to think about the item limitation for the UI If you are showing the 6 items then it will eventually take the minimum height and if items are more then that the it will show the full screen mode, I have created and example for you run the app and check if that's the desired output.

Comment: Check the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242475/discussion-between-martin-and-sagar-acharya).

Comment: I tried your updated code with 10 children in side grid view. It takes full screen as children > 6. Fractional sized box prevented bottom sheet from overlapping status bar but the problem is it takes full screen for 10 children leaving empty space at the bottom. I have opened up a chat as well, if you want we can discuss it there